# TypeError - update() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'

Tags: python

I have a method as,

```
@automation
def update(self, name, **kwargs):
"""
method body
"""
```

decorator:

```
def auto_call(f):
    def new_fn(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    method body
    """
```

automation testcase:

```
update(name, **kwargs)
```

here name has a value , **kwargs gets values from pre-defined dictionary.

Though I am using self, and followed as expected getting the below error.

```
TypeError: update() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'
```

Can you please advice if anything needs to be changed.

Comment: Does the `kwargs` in your test case contain a key `name`?

Comment: What is the value of `kwargs` in your test?

Comment: it has the keyword 'name'. I think that was the conflict it had. I changed the keyword in update from name to id. It seem to have this issue resolved.